# NFC Antenna matching

Tags: nfc, qucs

I am trying to follow the TI document on NFC antenna matching for the TFR7970A chipset.

http://www.ti.com/lit/an/sloa241b/sloa241b.pdf

I am under linux, and while I could try wine to use the smith chart simulation software, I was wondering if I could use qucs or qucs-s for simulating the matching circuit. (or other software available on linux).

Comment: I was able to import the S parameter file exported from my VNA, but I don't know how to use it to mimic the procedure in the above application note.

Comment: This sounds like a SW recommendation request in disguise, but my immediate question would be "what's wrong with wine?" If you know a software which solves your problem, why don't you simply try running it?

Comment: I'd like to understand the simulation process better, the smith chart simulation the pdf uses seems to handle a lot of things automatically.